# How does MetaTrader 4 script 'normalize' time?

Tags: c#, mt4

I try to understand the <kbd>MetaTrader 4</kbd> scripting language ( and convert a couple of scripts to C# ), so I started with the `PeriodConverter.mq4` ( it came with the MT4 install ).

Here are the values for the script:

`periodseconds == 1800`

`Time[start_pos] == 2013/11/20 07:00`

Here is the part of the script I'm having trouble understanding:

```
//--- normalize open time
rate.time=Time[start_pos]/periodseconds;
rate.time*=periodseconds;
```

this gives me a result of `2013/11/20 04:00` not `2013/11/20 07:00` as I would have expected

**More Detail:**

If I run the `PeriodConverter.mq4` script from MT4 saying I want to use the `FSTE100` 1hour data and the period multiplier I want is 5 hours, this will give `periodseconds` a value of `18000` ( see extracts from the script below ).

```
int      i,start_pos,periodseconds;
// Period() == 60 because I'm using a 1hour chart
// InpPeriodMultiplier == 5 because I want 5 hour increments
int      i_period=Period()*InpPeriodMultiplier; 
periodseconds=i_period*60;
```

so, `60 * 5 * 60 == 18000`.
If I now run the script using the data below:

`2013.11.20,07:00,6669.3,6677.5,6669.3,6674.2,456`

`rate.time` will be `04:00`
But how did it get this value? I tried converting it to C# to see if I could duplicate the result

```
var x = new DateTime(2013, 11, 20, 7, 0, 0); 
var ticks1 = x.Ticks / 18000;
var ticks2 = ticks1 * 18000;
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(ticks2);
```

But this gave me the same value that I start with `2013/11/20 07:00`

So how does MT4 get `04:00` from `07:00`? and is it possible to duplicate this in C#?

Thanks in advance.

**WITH HELP FROM JOSEPH THE PROBLEM HAS BEEN RESOLVED!**

Here is my working test code for anyone who needs it

```
    // working with seconds
    var x = new DateTime(2013, 11, 20, 7, 0, 0);
    // number of seconds since 12:00:00, 01-01-0001
    var sec1 = x.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
    // number of seconds since 12:00:00, 01-01-1970
    var sec2 = sec1 - (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
    // rate.time=Time[start_pos]/periodseconds
    var newRateTimeInSeconds = sec2 / 18000;
    newRateTimeInSeconds *= 18000;
    DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime((newRateTimeInSeconds * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond) + new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).Ticks);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the followings:

- In C#, 10mil ticks to 1 second. So, it should not be `/ 1800`. We should use `var sec1 = x.Ticks / (1800 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);`
- The BASE datetime value is 01.01.0001 in C#, while in MQL4, it is
  01-01-1970.
- This is very important distinction when we convert the datetime value
  to integer.
- If we take `integer viTime = TimeCurrent()`, viTime is the number of
  seconds ELAPSED since 01-01-1970.
- This is VERY important; vs C#'s Tick, which is the value of
  100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00,
  01-01-0001.
- To get the same MQL4's `integer viTime = TimeCurrent()` in C#, you need to get the `sec` value in C#, then deduct the `sec` value of 01-01-1970 from it.